# Moving element into another class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to move the a href element into the end of the p element.

```
<div class="press-text">
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <a class="press-file"></a>
</div>
<div class="press-text">
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <a class="press-file"></a>
</div>
<div class="press-text">
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <a class="press-file"></a>
</div>
```

I am using the following jquery

```
$('.press-file').each(function(){
$(this).find('.press-text p').appendTo($(this));
```

But something is not working.

EDIT: I am trying to have this

```
<p><a href="press-file></a></p>
```

in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use closest to find the `.press-text` element, and `append` instead of `appendTo` :

```
$('.press-file').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('.press-text').find('p').append(this);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/oyetij/1/edit) (open the console to see the transformed HTML)

Comment: Did you mean `sibling`? `closest` checks ancestors if I'm not mistaking

Comment: @J0HN Well, you could use both. In fact there are many paths.

Comment: Thanks dystroy. That works. Still don't see what I was doing wrong. I will read about closest.

Comment: `find` was looking into the descendants of the `a` element (`this`). And you should also look at the difference between `append` and `appendTo`.